# Particles (donut sprinkles) persistently too vertical at ~45 deg angle, will not lie flat on surface (of icing)

Tags: particles, hair

I've started over with the sprinkles step like five times, staring at the tutorial video, and every time the same thing happens. As soon as I switch orientation axis to 'normal', my sprinkles are mostly standing on end rather than lying on the surface. I've moved my donut back around the origin and I've moved the sprinkle model to hovering above the center of the donut and tried again, in case that somehow affected it, but no dice. Setting the origin to the geometry or to any point selected with the 3d cursor on the sprinkle model or the donut itself, at best, just changes how deeply the sprinkles are buried or how high they're floating, and no amount of rotating the sprinkle model fixes the angle. Horizontal, vertical, it's always tilted the same way. I've done the heatmap, the sprinkles are only appearing on the top of the donut, they're just... wrong. Turning rotation randomness entirely off makes it extra clear that they're coming up at like a 45 degree angle from the inside of the icing object. I've been fiddling with settings and googling and searching here and reddit and I'm completely stumped. (Source is set to emit from faces.)

[image: sprinkles jutting up out of the icing]

ETA: .blend file here: [image]

Comment: Look in the panel on the right - set "phase" to something other than 0, and then "randomize phase" will have an effect - these together will randomize the rotation. Adjust the position/rotation of the particle instance "base model" as needed to make finer corrections.

Comment: I reset that to make it extra obvious what was happening, but if I turn it back on they just spin around the vertical axis, still at a 45 degree angle. Rotating the base model does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Maybe apply rotation to the base (particle) model? It's hard to tell without seeing your file. You can upload it here if you like - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Uploaded and edited into the post, thank you--didn't realize there was a way to add it!

Comment: Yeah. Weird. I can get it pretty good, but if I select the sprinkle object and enter edit mode and try to use the grab tool, the mesh immediately changes shape/position. I've never seen anything like that. To get the best results I could, I deleted the particle system that was there, applied rotation/scale/location to both the sprinkle and the donut, and re-added the particles, After a bit of tweaking, it looks ok, but it doesn't solve the underlying issue. I'm not  sure, but maybe the donut being parented to the icing has something to do with it. Other than that, i'm lost.

Comment: The parenting to the donut was part of the tutorial, so it doesn't *seem* like it should be that, but I could certainly try undoing it while I add sprinkles... [testing] That worked!! I have absolutely no idea why that broke it because it was what he did in the tutorial but unparenting it absolutely fixed it! Thank you so much oh my god. I beat my head on different settings for SO LONG and it did not occur to me to try that.

Comment: No problem.If it's any consolation, I'm surprised it worked too.

Comment: I feel much better that it's not something completely obvious that I missed!